# Unique index - unique value in col1 OR col2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have two columns in table `tab`: `col1` and `col2`. I want make them unique in such way that if value `X` is inserted into `col1` then it should no be present in ANY row neither in `col1` nor in `col2` (and vice versa). So in fact I want to treat both `col1` and `col2` as same column (according to uniqueness). It seems to be simple but I can't figure out how to set proper index(es)...

Comment: Question: If it's the some type of data, why don't you store it in the same column? Without all background information, it sounds like a bad datamodel, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes I know this is strange but I need this "denormalized" data model. In fact `col1`,  `col2` will describe something like one-to-one relation without "parent" or "child" so data might be `(1,2)` or `(2,1)`, however if `1` occurs either in `col1` or `col2` it can't be present in other rows (one-to-one).

Comment: I doubt this can be done with indexes because of the kind of cross-column referencing that you need. You can certainly do it with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: Why do you think you need this denormalized data model? You are already encountering the first problems. I'm working with a large database (> 3TB), normalized to 3NF, with critical performance requirements. It all works fine, even with 1 million unique visitors per day. So, are you really really sure you have no other option?

Comment: I can't imagine other option: as I said I have to store informations about one-to-one relation between two abstract objects (their integer ID's in fact). It is impossible to order/sort those objects in any way so I never know which one is parent and which one is child. Also I have to store this information in single table...

Comment: An index preventing `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` is quite easy actually. `create unique index on foobar ( least(col1,col2), greatest(col1,col2))`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but I need cross-column uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule or a trigger. For convenience you need first a simple function which check if a value already exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_value_exists(val ANYELEMENT) returns boolean as $$
select val IN  (select col1 from tab union select col2 from tab) 
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

And a rule could be so:

```
create or replace rule check_uniqueness as on insert to tab where (check_value_exists(NEW.col1) OR check_value_exists(NEW.col2)) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Now if you try to insert a value which already exists, nothing will be inserted (DO INSTEAD NOTHING).

If you want better handle the case if values are already present (i.e. raise exceptions or warnings or something else), you probably better use a trigger (a little more code but more powerful):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_uniqueness() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (check_value_exists(NEW.col1) OR check_value_exists(NEW.col2)) THEN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'Value % or % already exists',NEW.col1,NEW.col2;
  END IF;
  return NEW;
  END;
$$LANGUAGE  plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER check_uniqueness_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON tab FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_uniqueness();
```